# c++ i change my list(and code) so it now handles Node* rather than Node Objects and it has caused an undefined reference error

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a A* in c++ but i had a problem with path following after a solution. My teacher suggested i use Node* and create them on the heap using new as my old was as allocating them on the stack and apparently you shouldn't return pointers on the stack so it was messing up the code at runtime.

The issue i am having is when i change my list to hold  rather than  i get this error:

```
undefined reference to `checkInClosedList(std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> >, int, int)'
undefined reference to `placeInOpen(std::list<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> >, int, int)'
```

When i call these functions:

```
if(placeInOpen(openList,best->getX()-1, best->getY())){
      //do something
}

if(!checkInClosedList(closedList, best->getX(), best->getY())){
    // do something
}
```

Given this code for best and openList:

```
list<Node*> openList;
vector<Node*> closedList;

Node *end;
Node *start = initiateStart(map);
openList.push_front(start);

while (!openList.empty()) {

    Node *best = openList.front();
    openList.pop_front();
   }

   //some other logic.....
```

The functions are defined as the following in a header file which is included:

```
bool placeInOpen(std::list<Node*>& v,int x, int y);
bool checkInClosedList(std::vector<Node*>& v, int x, int y);
```

Before i edited my functions and list to contain Node* this worked fine, why is it different for pointers ( i have handled the pointer manipulation properly, just this error is casuing me a headche)

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: You don't show us the use of `checkInClosedList`, which is where the error is.

Comment: Looks like you didn't change the definition of `checkInClosedList` to take the new list type. You'll need to do that.

Comment: sorry the error is on that as well, i thought i copied both functions and error message. updating now.

Comment: Did you change the signature of `checkInClosedList` implementation (not forward declaration which you probably have as well)?

Comment: Your update shows the function *declarations*, which you've correctly changed. You also need to change the *definitions*, which are somewhere else.

Comment: i have updated the code with both function declarations and error messages.

Comment: @MikeSeymour oh wow. i have been up too long, i completey overlooked that! if you want to post an answer ill vote it. Thanks a lot i was being a complete idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed the function *declarations* to the new type, but you'll have to change the *definitions* as well.

However, I'd suggest you *don't* make this change at all; your teacher seems to be talking nonsense. The `Node` objects were in the list, not "on the stack", with their lifetimes correctly managed by the list. Storing pointers to dynamic objects is a recipe for memory leaks and worse.

Answer (score 1):

`bool checkInClosedList(std::vector<Node*>& v, int x, int y);` is just a forward declaration. It tells compiler to expect somewhere else a working implementation of function with that signature. You have to change it as well in your function implementation.